# Sending photos on Facebook in private message

Tags: lumia, facebook, photos

Is it possible in Windows Phone (Amber) to send a photo to another person in a private message? I can't seem to figure this one out. Third-party apps are allowed.

EDIT: the Facebook app can do this now. You do not need to install the beta app for this any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Facebook beta for windows phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=93da5d29-daf0-4783-9ed5-a87b33247ec6) can do that! It is a new feature and not yet included in the released version of Facebook. I suggest you download the beta version which gets updated every few days with new features.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: fb]

### UPDATE

As of September 4th, 2013 [Facebook for windows phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=93da5d29-daf0-4783-9ed5-a87b33247ec6) can do that. No need to download the beta.

Comment: See my edit. There is no such button there!

Comment: @BramVanroy I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Shame, though, that it took MS so long to fix this.